# "len(sys.argv) < 2" not satisfied even when command called with only one argument

Tags: python

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'aklsjdlksajdkljl',
             'blog': 'dklasjkl9379343',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python ' + sys.argv[0] + ' [' + sys.argv[1] + '] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name


if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + " " + sys.argv[0] + " " + sys.argv[1] + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

When I type `./pw.py email` in terminal, it will go straight to the line:  `if account in PASSWORDS:` and will skip line: `if len(sys.argv) < 2:`

Why did it skip that line?

Comment: Please focus on one issue at a time. I've removed your second query; make that a separate question please.

Comment: I've tried to give this a more detailed title -- "issue regarding X" isn't generally detailed enough to let someone else know if they have the same problem (and thus if an answer is likely to help them) just by reading the title, which is one of the jobs a title should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sys.argv[1]` is defined, the length of `sys.argv` is 2 or greater. The test `sys.argv < 2` is only going to be true when `sys.argv` contains just 0 or 1 items. So the `if len(sys.argv) < 2:` is not skipped, the test is just *false* and the associated block is not executed.

`sys.argv[0]` is always set to the script name (here `pw.py`), so the length would be at least 1.

Note that you just used `python pw.py` (so no account or other arguments), you'd get an index error, as the following line tries to index to `sys.argv[1]`, a value that is *not set*:

```
print('Usage: python ' + sys.argv[0] + ' [' + sys.argv[1] + '] - copy account password')
# This raises an index error when len(sys.argv) < 2   ^^^
```

Comment: i removed sys.argv[1] but still it doesn't print that line.

Comment: @john: then pass in *no arguments*.

Comment: alright, i get it now. the len is what confused me. thanks

Comment: about the batch file: @py.exe C:\Python34\pw.py %*
(at)pause . . .  how to make this line work with ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know; I am not familiar enough with batch syntax.